# Release drag after finger lift (Alps touchpad)

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

How can I make it so after dragging it immediately releases the drag after finger lift? I have windows 10 and a Toshiba laptop with the Alps touchpad installed.

Comment: Very useful question , same touchpad, Toshiba notebook for me too , same annoying behaviour